# Ethernaut callenge 21 Dex - approving ERC20 token through proxy contract

Tags: solidity

[Original challege is here](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x0b0276F85EF92432fBd6529E169D9dE4aD337b1F)

```
  function approve(address spender, uint amount) public {
    SwappableToken(token1).approve(spender, amount);
    SwappableToken(token2).approve(spender, amount);
  }
```

I thought that approving ERC20 token spend through a proxy contract is not possible, how is the above contract able to approve on our behalf?

Answer (score 0):

It's written in the link you provided :

> Normally, when you make a swap with an ERC20 token, you have to
> approve the contract to spend your tokens for you. To keep with the
> syntax of the game, we've just added the approve method to the
> contract itself. So feel free to use
> contract.approve(contract.address, ) instead of calling
> the tokens directly, and it will automatically approve spending the
> two tokens by the desired amount. Feel free to ignore the
> SwappableToken contract otherwise.

They probably whitelisted the Dex contract on the token side so that you don't loose time approving on every try. But this is not standard practice at all, it just keeps the focus on the challenge itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its not possible. but contract is not calling approve method. Its called by msg.sender. Through out the transaction life cycle transaction initiator is always remain msg.sender. So whichever user calls this methods, Token approve will be called from msg.sender side not from contract side. This function is saving client to call approve separately before calling the contract.

Comment: so this is the TX i call this approve method, https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9cc2f090ca63174868ac06e0148592befe3d62f6a6762b3838932780506abeab. The internal TX show that the contract call approve internally right ?